# Cartan's subalgebra of square matrices with zero diagonal.

Tags: lie-algebras

What is the Cartan's subalgebra of set $D_{0 (n)}$ which consists of
n x n matrices with diagonal null?

I'm trying the case, $n=2$ and $n=3$, but I'm not coming to any conclusion,for $n=2$
$X= X^T; X\in D_{0(2)}$
ok, in the case 3x3 is not ok.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are asking. Are looking for Cartan subalgebras of a certain Lie algebra? But what Lie algebra? The square matrices with diagonal $0$ do not form a Lie algebra in general ($[\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}]=$?).

Comment: It's true, the exercise was wrong!!!